# UITableView cell does not show any background; UIView or UIImageView or otherwise

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have found many a post on this, but I can't get it. I have a TableView inside a UIViewController and so I have to have dynamic (prototype?) cells. I am trying to get familiar with Storyboard and IB. Here is what I have:

This is a UIViewController witha View on top and a UITableView on bottom with the custom cells
[image]

The colors are a UIView added to the cells for the top 3, and a UIImageView with a color image set on the bottom one (to test which one would work.... so far neither have.)

Here is the sidebar:

[image]

I have added the UIView/UIImageView as the backgroundView for all the Cells.

When I run this program, I get blank cells, and no colors. What am I doing wrong? Does it have to be done programmatically? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to use **static** cells, or you have to implement the table view  `datasource` protocol in your view controller.

Easiest way is to switch the table view to static and design away in IB to your heart's content. Both images and background color will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to have an image above my TableView, and I can't put a UIView in a UITableView controller, hence the UIViewController with a TableView inside. Is there a better way to do this? I will look into the datasource.... Thanks again.

Comment: Right - storyboard forces you to use a table view controller if you want static cells. You need just one dynamic cell prototype. Add the view in IB and color it `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Or you could have readily configured dynamic cells - but you need to change the cell identifier each time... this would be more cumbersome.